# how can I run java class with powershell in background?

Tags: java, powershell, background, start-job

I want to run java class in background by powershell.
I can't use '$'(which makes java run in background) in powershell command.
So I just made one more powershell script and run it in background by another one.
It goes like... `(start.ps1 --> run.ps1 --> WantToRunThis.class)`

```
Start-Job -Filepath "./folder/run.ps1"
```

-> This is start.ps1

```
java WantToRunThis args[0] args[1]
```

->This is run.ps1

I can make run.ps1 get started, but its status become completed immediately, so java doesn't work.
how can I fix this??

Final purpose of me is to run multiple java classes simultaneously in background...

Answer (score 0):

If double quotations PowerShell thinks $ is the start of a variable.  You can stop PowerShell from treating it like a variable by adding a tick mark in front of it e.g. `$.  Powershell will think that the $ is not a special character.  The single quotation marks will allow you to use the $ if want.

It sounds like you want start Java from PowerShell and have Java still running after PowerShell has completed. The single quotation marks will also allow you to use the $ if want.

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList 'java $WantToRunThis args[0] args[1]'
```

Comment: Thanks but its status still become 'completed' immediately :-(... I have no idea why powershell doesn't wait until java finish its job especially when using 'start-job'

Comment: Invoke-Wmimethod and start-job will run separately of the powershell script.  The script can end and they will continue.  I sound like you want Start-process.  This will start the process and wait till the process closes down. Then the next line of powershell can be ran.  Start-Process  -Wait -FilePath "java" -ArgumentList 'WantToRunThis -args[0] args[1]'